# Signed APK not generating in Cordova 8

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to build signed apk file. I am not sure why it is not generating. I have generated the signed apk in past with help of Stack Overflow.

I am doing the same thing this time but not sure why it is not generating.

I have created **ant.properties** and **build.json**. I also created **properties** file and I am using `cordova build android --release`. All these files are inside Android directory.

**ant.properties**

```
key.store=/Applications/mampstack-5.6.30-1/apache2/htdocs/testapp/Android/TestAppRelease.keystore
key.alias=TestApp
key.store.password=12345678
key.alias.password=12345678
```

**Build.Json**

```
{
    "android":{
        "release": {
            "keystore": "/Applications/mampstack-5.6.30-1/apache2/htdocs/testapp/Android/TestAppRelease.keystore",
            "storePassword": "12345678",
            "alias": "TestApp",
            "password" : "12345678",
            "keystoreType": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Keystore command which I used as follows:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore TestAppRelease.keystore -alias TestApp -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

`Cordova build android --release` generate unsigned apk file.

What else am I missing?

Cordova version is 8 and android minSdkVersion is 25. I have checked multiple questions and followed the instructions, however the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you can take your unsigned APK and issue this two commands to Sign your APK.

```
$ jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore {name}.keystore {apk_name_unsigned}.apk {apk_alias}
$ zipalign -v 4 {apk_name_unsigned}.apk {apk_name_signed}.apk
```

Answer (score 0):

to use the BouncyCastle keystore provider ...

```
"keystoreType": "BKS"
```

when **not** setting `"keystoreType": ""` it should use the default keystore provider.